# Window always opens blank even though code is written

Tags: java, eclipse, window, graphic

I am making a program which will open a class GUI called "Menu" when correct login info is put into a text field password field and a button called "login" is pressed. The problem is that the Menu window will open blank, not displaying what I have programmed into the Menu.

This is my code for Login class,

```
package ems;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JFrame loginFrame;
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login window = new Login();
                    window.loginFrame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Login() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        loginFrame = new JFrame();
        loginFrame.setTitle("Login");
        loginFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lblUsername.setBounds(112, 116, 74, 16);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        lblPassword.setBounds(112, 165, 74, 16);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        usernameField = new JTextField();
        usernameField.setBounds(198, 110, 134, 28);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(usernameField);
        usernameField.setColumns(10);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(198, 159, 134, 28);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String uname = usernameField.getText();
                String pword = passwordField.getText();

                if (uname.equals("test") && pword.equals("test")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginFrame, "Login successful.");
                    loginFrame.setVisible(false);
                    Menu menu = new Menu ();
                    menu.setVisible (true);

                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginFrame, "Login unsuccessful.");
                }
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(238, 210, 90, 30);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setBounds(108, 210, 90, 30);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        panel.setBounds(91, 86, 258, 163);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JLabel lblLoginToThe = new JLabel("LOGIN TO THE ELECTRICITY MONITORING SYSTEM");
        lblLoginToThe.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblLoginToThe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblLoginToThe.setBounds(26, 23, 418, 16);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(lblLoginToThe);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 63);
        loginFrame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is the code for the Menu class,

```
package ems;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import ems.Login;

public class Menu extends Login implements ActionListener{

    private JFrame menuFrame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Menu window = new Menu();
                    window.menuFrame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Menu() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        menuFrame = new JFrame();
        menuFrame.setTitle("Menu");
        menuFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        menuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menuFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblLoginToThe = new JLabel("THE ELECTRICITY MONITORING SYSTEM");
        lblLoginToThe.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblLoginToThe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblLoginToThe.setBounds(64, 22, 331, 16);
        menuFrame.getContentPane().add(lblLoginToThe);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 63);
        menuFrame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);

        JButton btnLogout = new JButton("Logout");
        btnLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                menuFrame.setVisible(false);
                Login login = new Login ();
                login.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnLogout.setBounds(307, 222, 117, 29);
                menuFrame.getContentPane().add(btnLogout);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setBounds(10, 222, 117, 29);
        menuFrame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);



    }
}
```

Both of these classes are under a package called ems.
I am very new to programming and help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating another `JFrame` inside of `Login` and `Menu`, which is wrong, theres also no need that `Menu` extends `Login`

Here is the fixed version for `Login`:

```
package ems;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Login extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login window = new Login();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Login() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        this.setTitle("Login");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lblUsername.setBounds(112, 116, 74, 16);
        this.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        lblPassword.setBounds(112, 165, 74, 16);
        this.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        usernameField = new JTextField();
        usernameField.setBounds(198, 110, 134, 28);
        this.getContentPane().add(usernameField);
        usernameField.setColumns(10);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(198, 159, 134, 28);
        this.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String uname = usernameField.getText();
                String pword = passwordField.getText();

                if (uname.equals("test") && pword.equals("test")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Login.this, "Login successful.");
                    Login.this.setVisible(false);
                    Menu menu = new Menu ();
                    menu.setVisible (true);

                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Login.this, "Login unsuccessful.");
                }
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(238, 210, 90, 30);
        this.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setBounds(108, 210, 90, 30);
        this.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        panel.setBounds(91, 86, 258, 163);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JLabel lblLoginToThe = new JLabel("LOGIN TO THE ELECTRICITY MONITORING SYSTEM");
        lblLoginToThe.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblLoginToThe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblLoginToThe.setBounds(26, 23, 418, 16);
        this.getContentPane().add(lblLoginToThe);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 63);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    }
}
```

And for `Menu`

```
package ems;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Menu extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Menu window = new Menu();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Menu() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        this.setTitle("Menu");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblLoginToThe = new JLabel("THE ELECTRICITY MONITORING SYSTEM");
        lblLoginToThe.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblLoginToThe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblLoginToThe.setBounds(64, 22, 331, 16);
        this.getContentPane().add(lblLoginToThe);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 63);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel_1);

        JButton btnLogout = new JButton("Logout");
        btnLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Menu.this.setVisible(false);
                Login login = new Login ();
                login.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnLogout.setBounds(307, 222, 117, 29);
        this.getContentPane().add(btnLogout);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setBounds(10, 222, 117, 29);
        this.getContentPane().add(btnExit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Still looking, but:

```
    menuFrame.getContentPane().add(lblLoginToThe);
```

The content pane isn't a container, you can't add multiple things to it.  You need to put everything in a panel (note panel != pane) and then add one panel to the content pane.

Also don't call `setBounds()` directly, use a layout manager.  That's another reason you could be seeing nothing: all your components are drawn outside of the window or some other similar error.  Layout managers will fix that.

EDIT: And as Edwardth said you have a habit of declaring your classes to be a thing (like JFrame) and then creating a *second* JFrame inside the `initialize` method.  Don't do that.

```
public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
       ...
    private void initialize() {
        loginFrame = new JFrame();  // BAD!
```

The `JFrame` was already made when you declared that `Login extends JFrame` you don't need a second frame.

Edwardth got the answer before me so go ahead and study his example and then mark his answer correct.  Ask in the comments below if you have further questions.

Here's my example of the Login class, without the `setBounds()`.

```
class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Login() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        setTitle("Login");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        usernameField = new JTextField();
        usernameField.setColumns(10);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField();

        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 0,2 ) );
        loginPanel.add( lblUsername );
        loginPanel.add( usernameField );
        loginPanel.add( lblPassword );
        loginPanel.add( passwordField );

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String uname = usernameField.getText();
                String pword = passwordField.getText();

                if (uname.equals("test") && pword.equals("test")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Login.this, "Login successful.");
                    setVisible(false);
                    Menu menu = new Menu ();
                    menu.setVisible (true);

                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Login.this, "Login unsuccessful.");
                }
            }
        });


        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        panel.add( btnLogin );
        panel.add( btnExit );

        JLabel lblLoginToThe = new JLabel("LOGIN TO THE ELECTRICITY MONITORING SYSTEM");
        lblLoginToThe.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblLoginToThe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));


        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));
        panel_1.add( lblLoginToThe );

        Box topBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

        topBox.add( panel_1 );
        topBox.add( loginPanel );
        topBox.add( panel );

        add( topBox );
        pack();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And the Main class:

```
class Menu extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Menu window = new Menu();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Menu() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        setTitle("Menu");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Box topBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

        JLabel lblLoginToThe = new JLabel("THE ELECTRICITY MONITORING SYSTEM");
        lblLoginToThe.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblLoginToThe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));

        topBox.add( lblLoginToThe ); // **********

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));

        topBox.add( panel_1 );  // *************

        JButton btnLogout = new JButton("Logout");
        btnLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Menu.this.setVisible(false);
                Login login = new Login ();
                login.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        topBox.add( btnLogout ); //****************

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        topBox.add( btnExit );

        add( topBox );
        pack();
    }
}
```